# spring security webSecurity.ignoring()

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I am using spring security via spring boot.
I have two kinds of rest services.

public/**  --> Every one can access and use these services

secure/**  --> Only authenticated users can use.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.addFilterBefore(requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/**").fullyAuthenticated();
}

@Bean
public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(true);
    filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("MY_HEADER");
    filter.setInvalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange(true);
    filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(false);
    filter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
    return filter;
}
```

When i want to access a resource under public i got exception.

exception: "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException"

message: "MY_HEADER header not found in request."

Why does my filter activated under public resource while it is configured as ignored resource?

Thanks is advance

Comment: Were you able to figure out the answer?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in `WebSecurity.ignoring()` as discussed in [Spring Security Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3958) when using Beans as Filters.

You can work around this by removing the `@Bean` annotation in your Filter declaration.

```
// @Bean - Remove or Comment this
public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {

    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(true);
    filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("MY_HEADER");
    filter.setInvalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange(true);
    filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(false);
    filter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
    return filter;
}
```